# Match text and return string python

Tags: python, regex

I got a string like the one below

```
400 get INTERNET/RESULTS http?=likelyanswer, (localhost) 900ms
```

Trying to return only 900ms and i seem to have problems with doing that, tried python regex still not getting favourable results.

Comment: "*tried python regex*" Show your attempts.

Comment: Btw, looks like you don't have to use regexes: `s.rsplit()[-1]` will do the trick, where `s` is your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your string always that predictable? Why bother with a regex?

```
In : x = '400 get INTERNET/RESULTS http?=likelyanswer, (localhost) 900ms'
In : x.split(' ')[-1]
Out: '900ms'
```

Comment: The result is not always predictable but comes in a format close to that. That is why I was intending on searching the whole file for matches before splicing. I guess I did not write my question well

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is the last space-separated item, you can just use `rsplit()`.

```
result_string = "400 get INTERNET/RESULTS http?=likelyanswer, (localhost) 900ms"
ms_time = result_string.rsplit(" ",1)[1]
```

That will return the last space-separated item.